# Spark Aggregator with ARRAY<BOOLEAN> input and ARRAY<LONG> output

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to implement a custom Spark Aggregator (a subclass to `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator`). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming I will be able to use it as an aggregation function like `SUM`.

What I'm trying to do is that I have a column of `ARRAY<BOOLEAN>` and I would like to GROUP BY another column and perform element-wise `SUM` if the boolean flag is set to `True`. The result of such aggregation should return `ARRAY<LONG>`.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
package mypackage.udf;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ElementWiseAgg extends Aggregator<List<Boolean>, List<Long>, List<Long>> {

    @Override
    public List<Long> zero() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> reduce(List<Long> b, List<Boolean> a) {
        if (a == null) return b;
        int diff = a.size() - b.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            b.add(0L);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.get(i)) b.set(i, b.get(i) + 1);
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> merge(List<Long> b1, List<Long> b2) {
        List<Long> longer;
        List<Long> shorter;
        if (b1.size() > b2.size()) {
            longer = b1;
            shorter = b2;
        } else {
            longer = b2;
            shorter = b1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < shorter.size(); i++) {
            longer.set(i, longer.get(i) + shorter.get(i));
        }
        return longer;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> finish(List<Long> reduction) {
        return reduction;
    }

    @Override
    public Encoder<List<Long>> bufferEncoder() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Encoder<List<Long>> outputEncoder() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The part I'm not quite sure is how to override `bufferEncoder` and `outputEncoder`. The default `Encoders` list does not provide encoding for `List`.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your assomption is right , I do agree with you:

```
package mypackage.udf;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ElementWiseAgg extends Aggregator<List<Boolean>, List<Long>, List<Long>> {

    @Override
    public List<Long> zero() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> reduce(List<Long> buffer, List<Boolean> input) {
        if (input == null) return buffer;
        int diff = input.size() - buffer.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            buffer.add(0L);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            if (input.get(i)) buffer.set(i, buffer.get(i) + 1);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> merge(List<Long> buffer1, List<Long> buffer2) {
        List<Long> longer;
        List<Long> shorter;
        if (buffer1.size() > buffer2.size()) {
            longer = buffer1;
            shorter = buffer2;
        } else {
            longer = buffer2;
            shorter = buffer1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < shorter.size(); i++) {
            longer.set(i, longer.get(i) + shorter.get(i));
        }
        return longer;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> finish(List<Long> reduction) {
        return reduction;
    }

    @Override
    public Encoder<List<Long>> bufferEncoder() {
        return Encoders.javaSerialization(List.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Encoder<List<Long>> outputEncoder() {
        return Encoders.javaSerialization(List.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Encoders.javaSerialization(List.class)` returns `Encoder<List>`, not `Encoder<List<Long>>` which is not compatible with the parent class.

Comment: i see , sorry for that , i upadte my answer